# How can I get the fireplace smoke smell out of my house?

Tags: cleaning, fireplace, smell

I recently got a new apartment with a wood burning fireplace. One of the first nights I had a fire and was sure to open the damper. After the fire was over, I went to bed but left the damper open. When I woke up I closed the damper. I went away for a few days and when I got back, my apartment smelt like smoke.

I opened the damper back up, cleaned the fireplace, cleaned the hardwood floors, cleaned ledges/countertops, and have a large air purifier running as well as ceiling fans. This has helped get rid of the smell, but it is still lingering in a few places. The flooring near the fireplace is hardwood. The carpeted flooring is far away and doesn't seem to contain the smell at all, so I didn't clean it. The ceilings are also very high. I can't seem to get rid of all of the smell.

How can I completely eliminate this smell?

Comment: Do you have glass doors or any doors on fireplace?  Some woods can really smell and doors are there for that reason.

Answer (score 2):

If you can find the source of the smoke smell, you could try a chemical smoke remover like ZEP Smoke Odor Eliminator:  http://amzn.to/1DuEMww

If that doesn't work or you can't find the surface that is holding the smell (and hence cannot use a cleaner like that), then you'd likely need to treat the entire room with an ozone machine.  These are used by professional cleaners that rehabilitate structures that have suffered a fire.  They aren't cheap to buy, and I don't know if you can rent one.  See an example Ozone generator here:  http://bit.ly/1xAXiTM